# MySql Decimal Datatype : not Inserting Proper Value

Tags: mysql, floating-point, double, decimal

**Short Version**
I am trying to insert Decimal value but after insertion it is storing 99.999999 for all Decimal values. I am using MySql 5.5.16.

**Long Version**

I am trying to create a table with schema below

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_name CHAR(100),
  group_name CHAR(100),
  lon decimal(8,6),
  lat decimal(8,6),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and my insert statement looks like

```
Insert into products (product_name , group_name , lon, lat) values
('Asparagus' , 'fresh vegetables' , 428743.9819 , 4512618.55);
```

I inserted 52 Values and in all `Decimal`, value is returning `99.999999`.

I also tried to use `FLOAT` which is returning `100.00000` and in case `DOUBLE` also i am getting `99.999999`.

Any Guidance will be helpful.

Comment: It's because you're specifying the length of your columns in the wrong way. Your code says `lon decimal(8, 6)` - 8 spaces, 6 reserved for digits after decimal point. Meaning your values can only go up to 99.999999 which is the maximum number they can store. Short version: use `lon decimal(12, 6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the values given to Decimal Variable. For me it is working fine.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_name CHAR(100),
  group_name CHAR(100),
  lon decimal(15,6),
  lat decimal(15,6),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Great !! It worked.. But how ?? that if the actual problem ??

Comment: It's based on Precision numbers you pass to DECIMAL function. To know further read MySql documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) you will see that you need a `decimal (13, 6)` because the first parameter is the precision... so to find it you have to count the global length of your maximal value.